# How to restrict properties for a domain being set from params

Tags: grails

I've got several properties in my domain class. However, I only want few of them to be set via the `params` object. What is a good way to do this?

Example:

Domain

```
class Color {
  String name
  String shade //don't want this set by params
}
```

controller

```
class ColorController { 
  def save() {
     json {
       def c = new Color(params?.color)
       c.save(flush: true)
       //..more code
     }
  }
}
```

If someone sends a request like:

```
  {"color": 
    {name: "red",
     shade: "light"
    }
  }
```

then user can change the `shade` property. How can I stop this?

Comment: Will User `save` or `update`?

Comment: They could do both. I am just trying to be on the safe side to not let the user enter data for the properties that they are not supposed to.

Comment: You can use a method `validateParams(params)` according to your need before setting it to the domain object. You also have to make sure that `shade` can be `nullable` in domain class. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do one of a couple of things:

1. If it is many properties, create a `transient beforeInsert() {}` and/or `transient beforeUpdate() {}` method in your domain class and handle setting (or not) the properties.
2. If only a few, override the setters in the domain class.

Since Groovy makes me not want to mess with getters and setters unless I absolutely have to, I usually use the `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Grails provides a [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) method on the controller to give you fine grained control of data-binding. For your example you could write this as:

```
class ColorController { 
  def save() {
     json {
       def c = new Color()
       bindData(c, params, [include: 'name'])
       c.save(flush: true)
       //..more code
     }
  }
}
```

In this case, only the 'name' field would be set on the `c` instance before attempting to `save`.

If you want to to additional validation on the incoming `params`, I would also suggest looking into using a [Command Object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) for the data binding.